# How much time will I need to invest to get the multiplayer achievements?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-revelations

I am totally new to any Assassin's Creed multiplayer, but I noticed that there are a set of multiplayer achievements in AC:Revelations.  I have to use a one-time code in order to get my copy to play online, and I probably would only be playing it for the achievements.

I've looked at the list of achievements, and I can't tell how difficult or rare some of these are.  Can someone give me an idea as to how long I'd have to play before I was able to get all these achievements?  Are there any that are particularly rare or difficult that I'd have to be extraordinarily lucky/skilled in order to get?

For reference, there is a list of achievements on [this page](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/assassins-creed-revelations/achievements/).  It's for the Xbox 360 version, but usually the Playstation Trophies are similar, if not the same.  The multiplayer achievements have "Multiplayer" after their description.

Comment: Which achievements are you referring to? Are you talking about the normal game achievements like "Best Served Cold" for completing the first DNA sequence? Or are your referring to the _challenges_ in multiplayer such as "The Elite Templar" for scoring 6000 points in a session? Or is it the _accolades_ like being "The Professional" for having the best KDR of all players? Or maybe the _Uplay actions_ you're referring to for reaching level 20. Unless there are other achievements on the consoles over PC that I don't know about, there aren't any other achievements that come from multiplayer.

Comment: Edited, I don't know what the overlap is with the PC, but I have linked a console list of the achievements.  It should be clear which ones are for multiplayer, as they have a different color scheme and their descriptions contain the word "Multiplayer" at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that list of multiplayer achievements and based on my own personal experience online, the majority of them will be very easy to get through regular play.  Here's some tips on getting some of the trickier ones.

#### Mastering the Art:

> Earn the INCOGNITO bonus (Multiplayer).

You need to get an incognito kill.  Depending on your skill level, this could be a tough one to get.  To get an incognito kill, you must fill up your approach meter to the max by keeping your target within your line of sight without running up to it or otherwise making yourself noticeable.  Note that you *can* run without reducing the meter if they are *not* within your line of sight.

#### Make the Headlines/Tactician:

> Obtain 12 different Accolades (Multiplayer).

> Score at least 2500 points in a session (Multiplayer).

To be successful in multiplayer, you need to always go for the quality kills.  You won't necessarily win by getting the most kills, you win by getting the most points and kills only grant you 100 points.  If you are more patient, you can get bonuses to earn you even more points.  Being fast an efficient will get you this achievement naturally.

This could be tough getting because you will need to be quick at getting your quality kills while still fending off pursuers.  I can't really help much with this, you just gotta be a machine and some other players can be *very* difficult to beat.  Though out of all the game types, **Deathmatch** might be the easiest to get it in as everyone is in a confined space and there aren't (normally) any lookalikes so should be easier to find your targets.

---

The other achievements you should be able to naturally earn if you go after the **True Templar** achievement of level 20.  Depending on your skill, it might take a couple of days or so of playing.  You shouldn't strain yourself over this too much if you plan on playing a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "platinium" it, you will have to earn all online trophies as well. The one which will need the more time is to reach level 20.
However, I find this much more easy to reach compared to games like BattleField, Red Dead Redemption and others where online trophies are quite tough.
But you will need anyway to invest some time in the mutliplayer mode. I enjoy it quite a lot and find the mechanics refreshing compared to other mutliplayer games like the ones mentioned above.

You can get more information on these trophies [here](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/assassins-creed-revelations/trophies/).

To me, while Brotherhood had some tricky ones, this one is clearly achievable without too many troubles.

Just for the records and to give you an overview, being an average+ player (but having played the Brotherhood multiplayer) I'm level 15 after 4 hours of play.